# I can't configure my computer to use XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I just installed Xampp but when I tried to open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` but an error message pops 
The error message says

> Error MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it.The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
>   Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL server isn't running, or you have a firewall blocking port 3306.

Else try this:

Add these lines in the host file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost # Additional IPv4 entry
::1             localhost # Existing IPv6 localhost entry
```

Answer (score 0):

1-) Try to check your mysql 3306 port on your firewall maybe you can turn off and try again
2-) Did u configrated your mysql from xampp username, password etc correctly ?
3-) Did u start mysql service correctly witouht any non permissons from windows firewall or security software ?
4-) Could you give me more specific informations about your enviremoent at least os and verison of xampp ?

Answer (score 0):

just start mysql on xampp control panel you should be good or further try freeing your port 3306 if all these still don't work, simply assign another port number for your mysqlserver but this should be your  last resort though because I strongly believe starting your mysql on your control panel should fix this error. I have experienced it before.